# Unable to create new Simulator in NC2 on Cygwin error : invalid command name "new"

Tags: cygwin, ns2

```
 $ tclsh
 % set ns [new Simulator]
 invalid command name "new"
```

I started today with NS2.
I'm running on Cygwin.
How to overcome this error.

I mostly think the error is due to the absence of this command

```
"#! /usr/home/homedir/very/long/path/tclsh"
```

But i dont know what this path corresponds in my system.

Answer (score 1):

`tclsh` is a component from tcl. The ns2 tclsh is e.g. `tclsh8.5`, and is required for running the executable `ns`. Ns2 "speaks" otcl, not plain tcl.

The ns2 interpreter is `ns`, not tclsh (tclsh8.5). Running simulations is as simple as `# ns simulation-file.tcl`. The executable `ns` knows the command `set ns [new Simulator]`. The tclsh* doesn't.
Examples : See ns-2.xx/tcl/ex/*, and "all ~3,000 examples" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

There are no examples with the ns2 versions from this century (AFAIK) which can run commands from the % prompt, to create any results.

Creating a basic simulation : Write a file.tcl or edit a current example, or generate files.tcl with e.g. NSG2.1.jar https://ns2blogger.blogspot.dk/2014/04/nsg-21-tcl-script-generator.html → `# java -jar NSG2.1.jar`

Introduction to "create simulations" : https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript1.html#first

Comment: Sir. Can you please provide me with a link to installation tutorials.My whole day is wasted now . I cannot get it to work

Comment: Im on windows 10

Comment: Cygwin : If you have a compiler (gcc, g++) version 5.x or earlier it should still be possible to build ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing . But usually not much chance with `nam-1.15`, I think. The preferred choice is a "Linux OS" installed to hard disk : Then no issues.